# How do I find the initials of the name entered in this string?

Tags: python

Say the user enters "joe smith". I can find the J but I'm not sure how to find the S seeing that the length of the string can vary.

```
name=input("What is your name")
initials=(name[0],#not sure)
initials=initials.upper()
print(initials)
```

I had a question like this similar on a quiz and apparently I'm supposed to use indexing. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
initials = ' '.join(map(lambda i: i.title(), name.split()))
print (initials)
```

or step by step:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
splited_initials = name.split()  # ["joe", "smith"]
titled_initials = [item.title() for item in splited_initials]  # ["Joe", "Smith"]
initials = ' '.join(titled_initials)  # "Joe Smith"
print (initials)
```

Comment: Thaks for the reply! I should have mentioned this in my question, but is it possible to do this using indexing?

Comment: You can check `name.index(' ')`, the next symbol will be `s`

Comment: When I try running this, it just prints the name entered with capitalization on the first letter of each word.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It will print each inital on a new line so you may want to add to an array or something before printing:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
names = name.split()
for name in names:
  if name != "":
    print name[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=input("What is your name")
initials=name.split(" ")
for word in initials:
  if word != "":
   print(word[0].upper())
```

Comment: This seems to work fine but is it possible I can use indexing to solve this?

Comment: Yes @Rajan, as you need the initial letter of the each word we can use the index "0". Hence it will get the starting letter from the each word.